# Cannot launch firefox 28 as jenkins user( root user can launch it well)

Tags: linux, firefox, jenkins

I'm trying to set up jenkins CI job and met this problem, see my log, jenkins user cannot launch firefox, but after I switched to root user via "su" command, root user can launch it normally, I guess it should be configuration file issue, can someone tell me which file or system property should I check and correct? Thanks!

```
jenkins@reed-Lenovo:/local/jenkins/workspace/SV_TEST/automation/robot$ firefox

(process:11695): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0
jenkins@@reed-Lenovo:/local/jenkins/workspace/SV_TEST/automation/robot$
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks it's the 1 of 1 question I posted and got 0 answer, it's ok and now I come to share the solution:

execute the following as root:

more /etc/ssh/sshd_config|grep -i x11 (make sure it's yes)
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sudo xhost +

than switch to jenkins, now it should be able to launch firefox normally.

The root cause might the X11 cache problem, it's broken somehow and need reset.